# How to Import Orange into Python Site-Package on a MAC

Tags: python, import, orange

I need to import orange into python on a MAC, i.e. do this:

```
import Orange
data=Orange.data.Table ("lenses")
print data.domain.features
```

When I tried to easy_install orange, permission to write into /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ was denied. Can someone please provide a newbie with some way to get around this?

I can also work with the python that comes bundled with orange located in /Applications/Orange.app/Contents/MacOS. But if I navigate there on my terminal, is there an easy way to grab my source files buried deep in my Documents folder?

I have been checking out sites for hours but there doesn't seem to be a clear path to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

To get past permission being denied, run `sudo easy_install orange`.  This will then ask for an admin password for your computer which you can provide, thereby granting the permission.